# How am I getting anonymous ratings on my app?

Tags: google-play-store

I thought that with the integration of Google+ into everything, all ratings were no longer anonymous.

That must not be the case, though.  While some of my app's ratings have a review and username linked to it, I also have unaccounted-for ratings with no review and username - they're just anonymous ratings.

How is this possible?

Comment: This skirts close to our "developer concern" off-topic reason, but I think it's okay to stay. I think it's as simple as: not everyone uses Google+, it's not available everywhere, and older devices are probably using older versions of the Play Store.

Comment: @AlE. But one can no longer rate an app without signing up for G+ first. I tried, and I failed. (and I won't sign up to that data monster). So the only points might be a) no enforcement on older Play-Store versions (huh? wouldn't they get updated automatically? Or only on "newer" Android versions?) or b) countries where G+ is not available (whom to shoot for bringing it to mine?).

Comment: Isn't there an API for app ratings too? Maybe that's it. This is probably something only Google can answer.

Comment: An older Google Play version seems like the most likely option. I'm trying to recreate it myself but it doesn't seem possible on my devices or my desktop browser.

Comment: Older Google Play, or someone who rated already as a 'Google User', if they update the review it stays as 'a google user'.